# how to let users only delete their own reviews Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5

Im new to rails and working on my project.When a user logs into his account i want to give him the ability to delete only his reviews and not the reviews of others.Currently one is able to log in an delete any reviews.I know this needs some authorization thing but im not sure.Here is my code...
here is the model relationship and controllers

```
class Airline < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :users,through: :reviews

    
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :airline

 

end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :airlines,through: :reviews 
   

  
    
end
```

Application controller

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Cookies
  
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :render_unprocessable_entity_response

  before_action :authorize
   
    

    private
    def authorize
      puts "hello",session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  
      render json: { errors: ["Not authorized"] }, status: :unauthorized unless @current_user
    end
  
    def render_unprocessable_entity_response(exception)
      render json: { errors: exception.record.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Session controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_action :authorize, only: :create
    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
          session[:user_id] = user.id
          render json: user
        else
          render json: { errors: ["Invalid username or password"] }, status: :unauthorized
        end
      end

    def destroy
        session.delete :user_id
        head :no_content
      end
    
    
end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    
    skip_before_action :authorize, only: :create
   
    def create
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
      end

   
      def show
        render json: @current_user
      end

     
      def index
        user=User.all 
        render json: user

      end

    private 
    
    def user_params
        params.permit(:name,:email,:password)

    end
end
```

Reviews controller

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorize


    def index
        review=Review.all
        render json: review

    end
    def show
        review=Review.find(params[:id])
        render json: review

    end
    def create
        review=Review.create!(review_params)
        render json: review,status: :created


    end

    def update
        review=Review.find(params[:id])
        review.update!(review_params)
        render json: review,status: :ok

    end

    def destroy
        review=Review.find(params[:id])
        review.destroy
        head :no_content
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
        render json: { errors: invalid.record.errors }, status: :not_found
    end

    private
    
    def review_params
        params.permit(:image,:date,:description,:destination,:seat,:user_id,:airline_id)

    end

   
end
```

Airline controller

```
class AirlinesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        airline=Airline.all 
        render json: airline,status: :ok

    end
end
```

on the front end

```
mport {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import "./Styling.css"
function ReviewCard({review,handleDelete}){
    const {id}=useParams();
    const{image,date,destination,seat,description,likes,dislikes,airline_id,user_id}=review;
   
    function handleDeleteClick() {
 
      fetch(`/reviews/${review.id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
  
      })
      handleDelete(review.id)
      
  
    } 


    return(
        <div className="reviewcard">


        
        <img  className="cardimg" src={image} />
        <p></p>
        <h6>{date}</h6>
        <h5>{destination}</h5>
        <h5>{seat}</h5>
        <Card.Text>{description}</Card.Text>
        <Card.Title>By {review.user.name}</Card.Title>
        <p></p>
        <h6>Likes: {likes}</h6>
         <h6>Dislikes: {dislikes}</h6>

        <br/>

        <Button  className ="btn btn-success"  > </Button>

        <Button  className ="btn btn-danger"  >  </Button>
        <hr />
        
        <Button  className ="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleDeleteClick}  >Delete</Button>
        
          
    
        
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does a  `Review` `belong_to` a `User`, and does `User` `has_many` `Reviews`?  Seeing the models would actually help  solve this more.  Assuming the relationships are set up, you just show a User their own reviews and allow them to delete them, if the reviews do not then how are you connecting the review to the user?

Comment: it has a has_many through relationship

Comment: So where you show the reviews to the user I would just limit it to that users reviews`current_user.reviews` or whatever your version is so that they only see their reviews.  If you do need to list all reviews then just wrap the delete button in a check, something like `<% if current_user.reviews.include?(review.id) %> delete button shown...` .  Can you show the HTML view where you want to limit this?

Comment: have updated the front end as well can ........ im not getting you .. i should write current_user.reviews in   def show
        review=Review.find(params[:id])
        render json: review

    end????

Comment: well whatever object you have to represent your current user, you just access the reviews they have through that and you can either just show them their own reviews, in which case they can delete them, or you have to show/hide the delete button unless the review belongs_to that user.  Do you have to list all reviews, or do you just want to list that user's reviews?

Comment: I have to list all the reviews.......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246515/discussion-between-wandering-and-rockwell-rice).

Answer (score 0):

In `destroy` you can write the following, assuming that your relationships between `Users` and `Reviews` are working.

```
# ReviewsController 
...
def destroy
  review = @current_user.reviews.find(params[:id])
  review.destroy!
  render json: {message: "Review Destroyed"}, status: :ok
rescue => e
  # handle `review.destroy!` exploding when `review` is `nil`
end
...
```

By running `@current_user.reviews.find(params[:id]`, you'll ensure that the user can only query the reviews that belong to them. Should they pass an ID of a review that doesn't belong to them, `review` will be `nil`.

Comment: Outside of the scope of the question, but it also looks like your `update` action on ReviewsController will allow for anyone with a session token to update any review. You can apply the same logic there. In addition, anyone with a session token can create a review associated to any user.

Comment: hey this code work wells only one prob......when i delete other people review it gets like deleted but on reloading its come back any idea why thats happening?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the review is in fact being removed from the database?